# how to know the channel i receive information from when i use nRF24L01 to connect between 3 of them

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

i am using nRF24L01 to connect between 3 of them ( 1 is master and the others are slaves) and i am using nRF24 library , my problem is that when the master receive something from the other slaves and do not know from which channel the infromation come so is there is a way to know from which channel

//master channel code:
  const byte addresses[][6] = {"00001", "00002","00003"};
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[1]); // mastr
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, addresses[0]); // carwl
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, addresses[2]); // carwl2

//slave 1 channel code :
  const byte addresses[][6] = {"00001", "00002","00003"};
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]); // carw1
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, addresses[1]); // mastr

//slave 2 channel code:
  const byte addresses[][6] = {"00001", "00002","00003"};
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]); // 00003
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, addresses[2]); // 00002

library i use: https://github.com/nRF24/RF24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the`RF24.available` function a pointer to a variable. The available function will write the pipe-number of the message to that variable.

An [example can be found in the documentation](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#ace7dd139fabc16b77cb8325faa07620f)

Answer (score 0):

The nRF24 is highly versatile and can be programmed for a number of different network topologies.  It appears you want either

1. One-to-many network - where the master node sends data to the slave nodes
2. Many-to-one network - where the master receives data from many slaves.

Both networks are achieved with the same radio channel (`RF_CH`) on all nodes.

For a one-to-many network you need to have a different RX address for each slave node.  Set the master TX address to the RX address of the corresponding slave  that you want to receive the data.  Done.

For a many-to-one network you are limited to 6 slave nodes.  On the master radio you will need to set the addresses of data pipes 0-5 to the slave TX addresses.  The master will be listening for data on all pipes and signal an interrupt whenever data is received on any of them.

To achieve bi-directional communication with a (practically) unlimited number of slave nodes, your best bet is to use the in-built ACK PAYLOAD feature of nRF24.  In addition to configuring a one-to-many network, you need to enable ACK payload on each radio node.  The procedure to follow is given in the nRF24L01 data sheet.  I can't recommend strongly enough how important that is to read and learn from.  You will be able to send a message from the master to one slave, and get data back from that node in the same radio transmission, auto-retransmit etc included in the bargain.  This way you also know which node the data are coming from - without needed to encode the identity of the slave node in the message.  It's incredible what these little radios will let you achieve!